# How to check if calculations are within ints higher and lower ranges

Tags: c#, casting, int

I thought this was going to be super easy but it has resulted in the need for more checks than i would like.

I have this code so far:

```
        if (funcType == "Mul")
            return (val1 * val2) <= int.MaxValue && (val1 * val2) >= int.MinValue;

        if (funcType == "Add")
            return (val1 + val2) <= int.MaxValue && (val1 + val2) >= int.MinValue;

        if (funcType == "Sub")
            return (val1 - val2) <= int.MaxValue && (val1 - val2) >= int.MinValue;

        if (funcType == "Div")
            return (val1 / val2) <= int.MaxValue && (val1 / val2) >= int.MinValue;
```

I need to check if when the calculations result in a number within the range of the int value type.

For example

```
int val1 = 1777777774;
int val2 = 477778777;
```

When added together the result is *-2039410745* (a valid int)
But this is not the correct answer (so to speak) and so the check is not working as desired.

I suppose i could declare val1 and val2 as longs to prevent the negative results and then do the comparison.

Would this be safe (i'd still be worried about the result hitting limits when doing multiplication), is there a better way that you could think of?

Many thanks,
Kohan.

Comment: Why don't u use Enum's for funcType ?

Comment: In my implementation funcTypes are extracted from a string using a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert one of the arguments to a [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) first, then the entire calculation will use 64-bit integers.

There's no danger of overflow so long as your original arguments remain typed as [`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx): `long.MaxValue` has more than twice the magnitude of `int.MaxValue * int.MaxValue`, similarly with `long.MinValue` and `int.MinValue * int.MaxValue`.

```
long longVal1 = (long)val1;

if (funcType == "Mul")
    return (longVal1 * val2) <= int.MaxValue && (longVal1 * val2) >= int.MinValue;

if (funcType == "Add")
    return (longVal1 + val2) <= int.MaxValue && (longVal1 + val2) >= int.MinValue;

if (funcType == "Sub")
    return (longVal1 - val2) <= int.MaxValue && (longVal1 - val2) >= int.MinValue;

if (funcType == "Div")
    return (longVal1 / val2) <= int.MaxValue && (longVal1 / val2) >= int.MinValue;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) keyword and catch the [`OverflowException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception.aspx).

Comment: Using exceptions for non-exceptional flow control is usually considered bad practice.

Comment: Well, manji's answer and my answer provide an alternative. I suppose it's up to the OP to decide what will work best for them.

Comment: Cool, didnt know about checked. Tried it out and it worked. However i am going to go with Lukes suggestion as it looks much cleaner and avoids catching exceptions.